# Explain the solution to the n-Queens Problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

The n-queens problem asks for a placement of n queens on an n × n  chessboard so that no queen can attack another queen. This means that no two queens can be  placed in the same row, in the same column, or on the same diagonal.

For no two of the n queens to be in the same row, there must be one queen in each row. We  can show that there is one queen in each row by verifying that every row contains at least one  queen and that every row contains at most one queen. We first note that $\lor^{n}_{j=1}p(i, j)$ asserts that  row $i$ contains at least one queen, and

$Q_1 = \land^{n}_{i=1}  \lor^n_{j=1}  p(i, j)$  asserts that every row contains at least one queen.

According to the text: For every row to include at most one queen, it must be the case that $p(i, j)$ and $p(k,j)$ are  not both true for integers $j$ and $k$ with $1 ≤ j < k ≤ n$.

My confusion with this last statement is that the two propositions $p(i,j)$ and $p(k,j)$ are only checking if two queens are in the same column $j$ while the rows $i$ and $k$ are representing rows in that column. How does this logic assert that no two queens can be in the same row? Shouldn't it be asserting that no two queens can be in the same column? Here is the equivalent formal propositional statement:

$Q_2 = \land^n_{i=1}  \land^{n−1}_{j=1}  \land^{n}_{k=j+1}  (¬p(i, j) ∨ ¬p(k,j))$ asserts that there is at most one queen in each row.

Rosen, Kenneth; Rosen, Kenneth. Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications (p. 34). McGraw-Hill Higher Education. Kindle Edition.

Comment: Is it possible that the authors have simply, by mistake, swapped "row" for "column" in part of their explanation? That wouldn't leave any lasting errors, since no matter which, you'll need to repeat the same condition with first and second coordinates interchanged _anyway_.

Comment: How about $Q2=\land^n_{i=1} \land^{n−1}_{j=1}\land^{n}_{k=j+1}(¬p(i,j)∨¬p(i,k))$? does this proposition assert that all rows have at most two queens?

Comment: It seems to assert that every row (or column, depending on which of the coordinates represent rows; I'm not sure) has _at most one_ queen.